# Upload to iTunes error: "app references non-public symbols"

Tags: ios, cocoa, xcode7, itunes

I am trying to upload my app to the iTunes store but I receive the following error,

```
iTunes store operation failed: The app references non public symbols
in Payload/XXX.app/XXX NSTextSizeMultiplierDocumentOption.
```

where XXX is my specific app's name.

However, according to the [AppKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Option_keys_for_importing_documents), the `NSTextSizeMultiplierDocumentOption` is not deprecated and it is public.

Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: AppKit is for OS X apps, not iOS apps. You can't use something for iOS unless it is documented for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that since I was using DTCoreText I was able to switch the "NS" to "DT" and it solved all problems.